# Can Aurelion Sol's stars damage Heimerdinger's Turrets?

Tags: league-of-legends

The title explains pretty much all. Does Aurelion Sol's orbiting stars deal damage to Heimerdinger's Turrets?

To "why don't you test this yourself" responses: I can't find a chance to test this since I can't find an Aurelion Sol or Heimerdinger in my recent games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aurelion's passive is considered an AOE Spell that deals damage to summoned units such as Heimer Turrets and Zyra Plants.

The turrets will also be auto-killed by the stars if they are below 25 HP since they are classified as minions.

While it's possible to kill those units with Aurelion it's usually best to do so with either auto attacks or the increased range on W since normal orbiting stars deal little damage and have low range thus they cause Aurelion to take damage from the turrets/plants.